# Print names of files with proper head

Tags: bash, awk, find, head

I want to get the name of files in current directory such that the first line of the file is equal to `myWord`. I wanted to combine `find . -type f` command with `-exec` option with `head -1 filename` but to no avail. Is there some clever, one-line solution to this problem?

Comment: Use pipes in bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` with `awk`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec awk '/myWord/{print FILENAME} {nextfile}' {} +
```

awk command will search first line of each file for the word `myWord` then it prints that filename.

Or using `gnu sed`:

```
find . -type f -exec sed '/myWord/F;Q' {} \;
```

Many thanks to @chepner and @123 for extremely helpful comments below this answer.

Comment: you should add `-maxdepth 1` to only do the current directory

Comment: `/myWord/ { print FILENAME; }; { exit; }` so that `awk` doesn't have to read anything except the first line, whether or not a match is found.

Comment: To minimize the number of `awk` processes, use `-exec awk 'FNR==1 && /myWord/ { print FILENAME }; { nextfile; }' {} +`

Comment: or you could use sed `sed '/myword/F;Q'`

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, Using `nextfile` is really great idea as we can use `+` with it.

Comment: @anubhava That does only search the first line.

Comment: You can also rewrite the awk as `awk '/myWord/{print FILENAME} {nextfile}'`

Comment: @123: Thanks!! Excellent suggestion, will edit further

Comment: @eNca: That's why I mentioned `using gnu sed` before that command